# YouTube: title & description translated – but ignored in search result display

Tags: youtube, localization

I have translated the title & description of [my YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0oY6u3VR8k) into several languages, incl. Spanish.

Now, when I set my browser locale to Spanish (using an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locale-switcher/kngfjpghaokedippaapkfihdlmmlafcc)), and [visit the video directly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0oY6u3VR8k) in Incognito/Private mode, I can see the Spanish translation – all good.

But when I [search for the video](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Vivid%3A+Cuenta+De+Banco), it does appear in the search results (at position 7), but the original (English) title and description is used:

[image]

Why? Is there a way to make the Spanish title appear?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 9 times. I’m voting to close this question because it looks to be obsolete, the video no longer appears on the search results using the link included in the question.